# Errors only happen when running django server with pipenv

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

I have a django project which runs with no errors when run without any virtual enviroments.
But when i run my server inside a after writing the command `python -m pipenv shell` **then** `python manage.py runserver` I encounter a few errors such as syntax errors when the syntax is perfectly normal and module import errors which would never occur without using pipenv

errors:

url = f"https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/110x140/p{photo_id}.png" - invalid syntax

ImportError: No module named 'PIL' (import worked outside of pipenv)

Comment: You should check your Python versions after running `python -m pipenv shell`. If there are syntax errors which are normally not there, that sounds like a Python 2 vs Python 3 issue.

Comment: Without showing any actual error, though, this question may be unanswerable and is not a really clear question.

Comment: I've added two of the errors i was getting

Comment: How could i be getting syntax errors in pipenv but no error outside pipenv on the same line???

Comment: The f-string syntax error means you are running with a rather old version of Python.  Again, check your Python versions used in pipenv. The ImportError means PIL is not installed in the virtual environment that pipenv uses.

Comment: You're not running the same Python version inside pipenv and outside pipenv. How you managed that, is anyone's guess. (Re)create (another) virtual environment, and make sure you use the correct (same) Python versions. Also make sure you install PIL in the virtual environment.